# JS namespacing code

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have written a wrapper for my code that allows basic namespacing and I'd like some feedback on how it can be improved.

It is designed so that a module can define it's namespace and get access to all of the parent namespaces. These are spread in reverse order across the arguments of the module (i.e. `first.second.third` is passed as `(third, second, first)`).

Here is the code itself:

```javascript
(function(name, globals, factory) {
  var namespaces = [];

  name.split('.').reduce(function(object, key) {
    if (typeof(object[key]) !== 'object') {
      object[key] = {};
    }

    namespaces.push(object[key]);

    return object[key];
  }, globals);

  factory.apply(null, namespaces.reverse());
})(/* namespace */, this, function(util, app) {

});
```

It is designed for use in the browser, hence `this` being passed as the `globals` argument (`this` is `window` in the browser).

Here's an example of how I use it:

```javascript
(function(name, globals, factory) {
  var namespaces = [];

  name.split('.').reduce(function(object, key) {
    if (typeof(object[key]) !== 'object') {
      object[key] = {};
    }

    namespaces.push(object[key]);

    return object[key];
  }, globals);

  factory.apply(null, namespaces.reverse());
})('app.util', this, function(util, app) {

  util.doSomething = function() {};

  // I expose all "levels" of the namespace so that it can be used like this:
  util.doSomethingElse = function() {
    app.core.performAction();
  };  
});
```

One or two questions/thoughts I've had on it:

1. Is there a real reason I should use `this` instead of `window`? I'm not really sure why I started using it, I think I saw someone else using it and just picked it up.
2. Is there any way to shorten it? I know it's only ~400 bytes but it would still be nice to simplify it further. I could use `map` instead of `reduce` but I tried it and it only saved on one line and partially sacrificed readability and simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a real reason I should use `this` instead of `window`?

`window` is a browser-only global. `this` is the current execution context. If your script runs in the global space, `this` is `window`. Either way will do.

> Is there any way to shorten it?

Yes, by probably separating the code from the namespacer functionality.

```
(function(name, globals, factory) {
  var namespaces = [];

  name.split('.').reduce(function(object, key) {
    if (typeof(object[key]) !== 'object') {
      object[key] = {};
    }

    namespaces.push(object[key]);

    return object[key];
  }, globals);

  factory.apply(null, namespaces.reverse());
})(/* namespace */, this, function(util, app) {

  // Code here

});
```

If the code were to grow, you'd either be piling them up into that function, or rewriting the entire thing again in another file. Copy-pasting code is proably code smell. I suggest you split off the top part into a standalone function. The way I did this before is define it in a utilities global.

```
;(function(global, utils){

  utils.namespace = function(namespace, closure){
    closure.call(null, namespace.split('.').reduce(function(parent, current, index, keys){
      if(!parent.hasOwnProperty(current)) parent[current] = {};
      return parent.current;
    }, global));
  };

}(this, this.utils = this.utils || {});

// usage

utils.namespace('foo.bar.baz', function(baz){
  // baz is `window.foo.bar.baz`
});

utils.namespace('path.to.app', function(app){
  // app is `window.path.to.app`
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you place a semicolon right before the anonymous function in your last snippet? I've seen that done before, but wasn't 100% sure why (I thought it was something to do with ending the "last line", but I'm not sure why'd there by a "last line").

Comment: @SirPython It's a habit :D It's a practice to guard an IIFE from naive concatenation of files. Prevents the parens from being interpreted as something else, like a function call (i.e.: `functionNameFromPreviousFile;(function iife(){}())` instead of `functionNameFromPreviousFile(function iife(){}())`)

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to make a few improvements using `map` instead of `reduce`, but I'm sure there's still something I can improve.

```javascript
(function(name, globals, factory) {
  var namespaces = name.split('.').map(function(key) {
    globals[key] = typeof(globals[key]) === 'object' ? globals[key] : {};
    globals = globals[key];

    return globals;
  });

  factory.apply(null, namespaces.reverse());
})(/* namespace */, this, function(/* namespace pieces */) {

});
```

Changes:

1. Replaced `reduce` with `map` so I don't need an array to store the namespace values in.
2. Now uses a ternary conditional instead of a full conditional to replace a value if it is not an object.